# Angular - Form and $pristine does it work with nested inputs?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following form.

A couple of issues I am facing:

1 - I'm unable to check for `$pristine` on the form with `console.log($scope.myFirstForm.$pristine);` I'm seeing the error: `cannot read property '$prestine' of undefined'.
Based on my code is this actually possible i.e. to use when the input fields are nested within several div tags?

2 - To clear the fields I'm currently having to do each field individually, is it possible to do at the form level which clears all input fields with that?

```
<form name="myFirstForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
        <input ng-model="main.pToAdd" type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row homeTopBackgroundColor">
     <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
       <h5>Room</h5>
     </div>
     <div class="row large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
             <input ng-model="main.o1ToAdd" type="text" />
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
        <input ng-model="main.opToAdd" type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

SOLVED:
In my routes file I was specifying a controller (so 2 controllers on one page). I was checking on the child scope not the parent hence not being found. So I removed the setting of a controller in the routes file and just specified it in required places of HTML.

Comment: Where are you assigning to `myFirstForm` on `$scope` ?

Comment: Not aware of that - guess thats a starting issue. I assumed Angular did that itself?

Comment: It does not. The `$pristine` property of `FormController` would need to be accessed by a custom directive on the form. From there, you could assign it to the scope or otherwise do what you need to with it.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand - I'm on my first Angular app here.
So you are saying instead of `form` I need to make a custom directive or do i just use `ng-model` to do that?

Comment: Actually, just double-checked the docs, and your `name="myFirstForm"` *should* be publishing a variable to your scope... it may only exist inside the form, though, not in the controller scope of the page.

Answer (score 1):

First the form included in the controller will automatically be in the scope of that controller.

Inputs inclosed in the form are part of the form no matter how nested it is. (use the name attr to be able to validate them.. assign errors and states to them)

Setting the form to pristine state will clear even the validations .. setting the main object in your case to {} will clear all the input fields.

`cannot read property '$prestine' of undefined -> can be because you are calling it in the controller before the form is assigned in the view. try the same thing on a click of any button should not give the same answer.

Comment: Thats where I placed that code `console.log($scope.myFirstForm.$pristine);` on a button click and it gave that error.

Comment: try console the $scope and see the properties

Comment: is this form actually defined on that scope .. you need to go to the basics, sometimes it's something you overlooked and if it is not defined try passing the form in the click button and console it.. ng-click="func(myFirstForm)"

Comment: I did a console.log of `$scope` and couldnt see it there
When you say form defined on that scope. How do I that? Sorry if that sounds really basic, I'm new to Angular.

Comment: This form html is inclosed in ng-controller="Your controller", I mean the form html elements are inside the element where the controller is defined right?

Comment: ex. <div ng-controller="AController"><form></form></div>

Comment: That didnt work. Infact I just recalled something. In my routes I have specified a controller. But in addition from my index.html there is a main controller also acting - could this be an issue 2 controllers on 1 page?

Comment: Can i specify which controller this hsould be on `<form name="myFirstForm">`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104681/discussion-between-alex-mounir-and-usermod2).